# Using a 3rd party web service API in a joomla / php application

Tags: php, api, joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating a custom application using the joomla platform. I have some 3rd party web service APIs that I need to use in my application.

I'm not really sure how I will send and get the information from the API. Is it possible to do the same thing a browser does i.e. send get/post requests to the API, and have a response returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the JHttpTransportCurl class in the joomla API. Looks like that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please take at look at the the curl extension.  This allows you to make calls like a browser.

[curl Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)